# Help with SED command to replace text in several files

Tags: linux, debian, sed

EDIT: I found the solution. This command works, in case someone finds it useful. The i.bak modifier makes a backup of every changed file.

```
find /pathoffilestochange -name "*.php" | xargs sed 's|/wrong/path/|/correct/path/|g'
```

Hello,

I want to change a path inside dozens of .php files. I dont know how to use sed, but I got this command somewhere on the internet before and have succesfully used it.

```
 find /ruta -name "*.txt" | xargs sed -i.bak 's/charset=Foo/Bar/g'
```

Except now I need to change the delimiters to a different character, hece the @. This is my current command:

```
find /pathoffilestochange  -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i.bak 's@charset=/wrong/path/@/correct/path/@g'
```

It is not working, and it doesnt give any errors, but I check the files and they remain the same.

I am executing the command as root, which is the file owner, and the permissions seem to be OK, so that must not be the issue. I am running Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replacing the reserved delimiter with @ won't work. What you have to do is to escape your slashes like this `\/` With the `\` character, you cancel the special meaning of a character in a regular expression.

So, your command needs to look like this:

`find /pathoffilestochange  -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i.bak \ 's/charset=\/wrong\/path\//\/correct\/path\//g'`

It's confusing, but that's how regexes are working.

By the way, with the single backslash after `-i.bak` I canceled the meaning of the new line character, so I could this command on two lines for easier readability.

Comment: No, you don't need to escape the slashes if you change the delimiter to something else.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and it kind of makes sense to do this for a pathname, but I prefer the escape route, mostly out of habit (the "that's the way I learned it" habit ;)) and to prevent confusion because so I always have to escape this character.

Answer (score 1):

What version of sed are you using? Works for me:

```
$ cat foo 
hello charset=/wrong/path/fcc yes
$ find . -name foo | xargs sed -i.bak 's@charset=/wrong/path/@/correct/path/@g'
$ cat foo
hello /correct/path/fcc yes
$ sed --version
GNU sed version 4.2.1
```